# how to select rows that contains non-english characters in sql server 2005(it should filter only non-english chars, not special characters)

Tags: sql-server

As my table contains non-English(contains characters in different languages) characters and special characters in a column. I need filter only non-English characters. It should filter any special characters.

i tried using different methods to filter but failed to filter few rows. someone please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

ex: 
column name **LOCATION** contains following rows :

**row 1**: துய இம்மானுவேல் தேவாலயம், North Street, Idyanvillai, Tamil Nadu, India

**row 2**:Dr.Hakim M.Asgar Ali's ROY MEDICAL CENTRE™ Unani Clinic In Kerala India, Thycaud    Hospital Road, Opp. Amritha Hotel,, Thycaud.P.O.,, Thiruvananthapuram, Kerala, India

**row 3**: ಕಾಳಿಕಾಂಬ ದೇವಿ ದೇವಸ್ಥಾನ, Shivaji Nagar, Davangere, Karnataka, India

As the above contains characters in many language. can any one help me to select only **row 2** thanks.

Comment: filter in the sense selecting rows which contains non-english charactes. To be more specific i m editing this question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

T-SQL's string-handling capability is pretty rudimentary.

If the "non-English" fields are distinguished by their use of Unicode UTF-16, you can try something like

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyField = Cast(MyField AS VARCHAR)
```

to pull only rows that are expressible in UTF-8.

The only way I know how to test whether a field is drawn from an arbitrary set of characters is with a [user-defined function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191007.aspx), like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsAllowed (@input VARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS BIT
-- Returns 1 if string is allowed, 0 otherwise.
-- Usages: SELECT dbo.IsAllowed('Hello'); -- returns 1
--         SELECT dbo.IsAllowed('Hello, world!'); -- returns 0
-- Note CHARINDEX is not case sensitive so @allowables doesn't need both.
--      VARCHAR(MAX) is different under SQL Server 2005 than 2008+
---     and use of defined VARCHAR size might be necessary.
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @allowables char(26) = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  DECLARE @allowed int = 0; 
  DECLARE @index int = 1;
  WHILE @index <= LEN(@input)
    BEGIN
    IF CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@input,@index,1),@allowables)=0
      BEGIN
      SET @allowed = 0;
      BREAK;
      END
    ELSE
      BEGIN
      SET @allowed = 1;
      SET @index = @index+1;
      END
    END
  RETURN @allowed
END
```

User-defined functions can be applied to columns in SELECT, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE dbo.IsAllowed(MyField) = 1
```

Note the schema name (`dbo` in this case) is not optional with user-defined functions.

If a T-SQL user-defined function is inadequate, you can also use a [CLR Function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189876.aspx). Then you could apply a regexp or whatever to a column. Because they break portability and pose a security risk, many sysadmins don't allow CLR functions. (This includes Microsoft's SQL Azure product.)

Comment: thanks for your answer but with the above query i still have few rows containing integers and special characters which i need to ignore. is there any method to ignore special characters with the above query???

Comment: Did it work? If so you should mark the question as "answered". That way Stack Overflow will not show it as an open question.

Comment: ya it worked but not exactly as expected. but i got a way to find answer for that.

Answer (score 8):

If you have all the allowed special characters, following select statement should select all columns with only English and the allowed special characters:

```
select column_name from table_name where column_name like '%[^a-z, .-™]%';
```

*You can add all the allowed special characters inside the square brackets.*

Answer (score 4):

Got a great answer for my question.

```
     select ID, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, REFERENCE, LOCATION, VALIDATE,
     patindex('%[^ !-~()"]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,LOCATION) as [Position],
     substring(LOCATION,patindex('%[^ !-~()"]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,LOCATION),1) as [InvalidCharacter],
     ascii(substring(LOCATION,patindex('%[^ !-~()"]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,LOCATION),1)) as [ASCIICode]from  dbo.RADAR_SEARCH where patindex('%[^ !-~()"]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,LOCATION) >0
```

EDIT1: 
Explanation for above answer

> Above query filters only non-English chars in **Location** column in which special characters are not included.

NOTE: Tested only in MS-SQL.

Comment: That is probably faster than what I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I used this for converting emails which has non-english characters to NULL. (MS SQL)

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_character_test(@kontrol nvarchar(MAX))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
DECLARE @intFlag2 INT
SET @intFlag2 = 1
DECLARE @SonucFlag INT
SET @SonucFlag=0
DECLARE @SonucFlag2 INT
SET @SonucFlag2=0
WHILE (@intFlag <=LEN(@kontrol))
BEGIN
WHILE (@intFlag2 <=62)
BEGIN
IF CAST(SUBSTRING(@kontrol, @intFlag, 1) as varbinary(2))
=CAST(SUBSTRING('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', @intFlag2, 1) as varbinary(2))
SET @SonucFlag=@SonucFlag+1
SET @intFlag2 = @intFlag2 + 1
END
SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
SET @intFlag2 = 1
END
IF @SonucFlag=LEN(@kontrol)
SET @SonucFlag2=1
ELSE
SET @SonucFlag2=0
RETURN @SonucFlag2
END


USE master;
GRANT EXEC ON dbo.ufn_character_test TO PUBLIC


SELECT ADR_EMAIL,
CASE WHEN ADR_EMAIL NOT LIKE '%[%]%'
AND ADR_EMAIL NOT LIKE '%@%@%%'
AND ADR_EMAIL NOT LIKE '.%'
AND ADR_EMAIL NOT LIKE '%.'      
AND dbo.ufn_character_test(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ADR_EMAIL,'.',''),'@',''),'_',''),'-',''))=1
AND ADR_EMAIL LIKE '__%@%__.__%'
THEN ADR_EMAIL ELSE NULL END AS EMAIL
FROM EMAILTABLE
```

Comment: Hi Emre. Welcome! Think you might mean 'selecting' rather than 'electing'