# T-SQL Select to Check Column For Non-English (Latin1) Characters

Tags: t-sql, select, ascii, collate, patindex

The default language on my database is set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

I'm looking to return results where the `name` field contains characters from another language, such as Arabic or Chinese):

> Albra اابومحمد

I've tried the following pieces of code below in my WHERE clause, but the result set is always empty:

1. `a.Name NOT LIKE '%[^A-z]%'`
2. `PATINDEX('%[A-Z,0-9]%',a.Name) > 0`
3. `ASCII(a.Name) NOT BETWEEN 65/* A */ and 90/* Z */
   AND ASCII(a.Name) NOT BETWEEN 97 /* a */ AND 122 /* z */`
4. `a.Name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z]%'`

**Update**

I'm using SQL Server 2012 (not SQL Server 2005.)  I tried the code in the accepted answer to "[how to select rows that contains non-english characters in sql server 2005(it should filter only non-english chars, not special characters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139258/how-to-select-rows-that-contains-non-english-characters-without-including-specia)" but it does not work on my database.

Comment: (1) When you say 'to no avail' what were the actual results?  (2) Did you already populate the name column with non-Latin strings?  Are you trying to do a select or an update query?

Comment: Trying to do a SQL select.  Just trying to identify data that would be included in this result set.  By no avail, I mean I didn't get what I was looking for.  I setup a dummy name listed above that I wanted in the result set.  All I got was a return on Null records or records that had a character outside of A-Z...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to select rows that contains non-english characters without including special characters in sql server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139258/how-to-select-rows-that-contains-non-english-characters-without-including-specia)

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  I'm using SQL Server 2012, and I already tried the function in the link provided and it does not work.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please add the error messages and result sets to your question: don't make it hard for answerers to find them in comments. When you say: "The link that identified as a possible duplicate was explored prior to this posting and does not work", what happened when it did not work. Also, I suggest making a minimal database that reproduces your problem, so that others can try it.