# How to copy non-English ir English data into another column in same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to copy non-English data to another column of a same table in SQL Server but I am not getting how to do that.

This is the image in which column `Work_Name` is having both English and non-English data and I am trying to copy only non-English data to another column.

[image]

How can I do that, can anyone please help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to select rows that contains non-english characters without including special characters in sql server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139258/how-to-select-rows-that-contains-non-english-characters-without-including-specia)

Comment: you may need to take a look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21140501/1666800