# How to identify unicode text in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Table1 has nvarchar column called umsg which contains unicode text and some time english also.

I want to find out English text present in umsg column.

```
select * 
from table1 
where 
    RDate >='01/01/2014' and RDate < '09/26/2017' 
    and umsg = convert(varchar(max), umsg)
```

I used above query that work fine in regional language but some time fail.
Suppose col contain text like 'ref no Ã©tÃ©'
I think above message is unicode, if I used above query, it/sql is showing me as English not unicode.How to handle this.

```
Table :
Id  Date                      Umsg
1   2017-09-12 00:00:00.000   The livers detoxification processes.
2   2017-09-11 00:00:00.000   Purposely added 1 
3   2017-09-10 00:00:00.000   फेंगशुई के छोटे-छोटे टिप्स से आप जीवन की विषमताओं से                       स्वयं को बचा सकते
4   2017-09-17 00:00:00.000    तनाव एक लाइलाज बीमारी कतई नहीं है। कुछ लोग तनाव को                                     आसानी से झेल लेते ह
5   2017-09-17 00:00:00.000    ref no Ã©tÃ©
```

Above is data present in my table.
But I want data/Output like :

```
    Id      Date                      Umsg
    1   2017-09-12 00:00:00.000   The livers detoxification processes.
    2   2017-09-11 00:00:00.000   Purposely added 1
```

Comment: @Jui Test, Try to use nvarchar instead of varchar in where condition. convert(nvarchar(max), umsg).

Comment: Yes,I am using sql server 2012

Comment: why you use varchar instead of nvarchar

Comment: I can't use nvarchar,If I used it will give all unicode message also.I want only english message.Column is already Nvarchar type.Converting it into nvarchar again, not meaningful.

Comment: @Jui Test What the output will look like if the string contains both unicode and ascii characters?

Comment: You can look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139258/how-to-select-rows-that-contains-non-english-characters-in-sql-server-2005it-sh

Comment: I want data/Output like :

    Id      Date                      Umsg
    1   2017-09-12 00:00:00.000   The livers detoxification processes.
    2   2017-09-11 00:00:00.000   Purposely added 1

Comment: If I used this query : select * 
from table1 
where 
    RDate >='01/01/2014' and RDate < '09/26/2017' ,am getting output like :  Id Date Umsg 1 2017-09-12 00:00:00.000 The livers detoxification processes. 2 2017-09-11 00:00:00.000 Purposely added 1
    and umsg = convert(varchar(max), umsg)                                                  5   2017-09-17 00:00:00.000    ref no Ã©tÃ©.I don't want 5 Id row to come.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

check below :

```
;WITH CTE
 AS (
 SELECT ID,
        DATE,
        umsg,
        CASE
            WHEN(CAST(umsg AS VARCHAR(MAX)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS) = umsg
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END HasSpecialChars
 FROM <table_name>)
 SELECT ID,
        DATE,
        umsg
 FROM CTE
 WHERE Date >= '01/01/2014'
       AND Date < '09/26/2017'
       AND HasSpecialChars = 0;
```

**Desired Output :**

```
ID  DATE                     umsg
1   2017-09-12 00:00:00.000  The livers detoxification processes.                                                                     
2   2017-09-11 00:00:00.000  Purposely added 1
```

Hope, it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You did not answer what you want in case there are some unicode and  some ascii characters in the same string, so I give you 1 idea and 1 solution for the case if you want only to find "pure English" or "mixed" rows.

You need a table of natural numbers to do this .In case you have no such a table you can generate it like this:

```
select top 1000000  row_number() over(order by getdate()) as n
into dbo.nums
from sys.messages m1 cross join sys.messages m2;

alter table dbo.nums alter column n int not null;

alter table dbo.nums add constraint PK_nums_n primary key(n);
```

Now that you have a table of natural numbers we are going to decompose your strings into single characters to check if `ascii(character)` = `unicode(character)`:

```
declare @t table(col Nvarchar(200));
insert into @t values
(N'ref no Ã©tÃ©'), (N'The livers detoxification processes.'), (N'फेंगशुई के छोटे-छोटे टिप्स से आप जीवन की विषमताओं से')

select t.col, n, substring(t.col, n, 1) as nth_character,
       ascii(substring(t.col, n, 1)) as ascii,
       unicode(substring(t.col, n, 1)) as uni
from @t t join dbo.nums n
       on n.n <= len(t.col); -- this is to give you an idea how to see if it's unicode character or ascii

with cte as
(
select t.col, n, substring(t.col, n, 1) as nth_character,
       ascii(substring(t.col, n, 1)) as ascii,
       unicode(substring(t.col, n, 1)) as uni
from @t t join dbo.nums n
       on n.n <= len(t.col)
)
select col, 
       case
            when sum(case when ascii = uni then 1 else 0 end) = count(*) then 'English only'
            else 'Not only English'
       end as eng_or_not
from cte
group by col -- row level solution
```

The first part of the code shows you your string character by character along with character's ascii ande unicode code: where they are the same it's ascii character.

The second part just check if all the characters are ascii.

[image]