# What is the special character VT? I need to replace it from MS SQL

Tags: sql, special-characters

Somebody left this special character in the SQL table

It more looks like ♂ sign but thinner or a vertical tab Char VT sign, but when I copy it to word document or SQL query page it displays like a white space. Only Notepad++ configures it as VT sign. I tried to copy that sign to google search bar but what I saw is only a white space.

I wonder it must come from different language keyboard or something I have no idea what's about.

Anyone recognize it?

---------------update--------------------

I found out this special character  doesn't display in here correctly. [image: I added a picture here]

Comment: Can you replace everything but say regular letters and numbers instead of trying to find that character specifically?

Comment: Use `unicode()` to find out the value for that character. Then use that in `replace()`.

Comment: I agree with @SQLChao, you can use an SQL function to find the true value of the character, then you can reliably replace it.

Comment: here is ur possible solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46537308/how-to-identify-unicode-text-in-sql/46561056#46561056

Answer (score 3):

Represent the VT (vertical tab) character as a Transact-SQL string with `char(11)`.

Almost any keyboard will send this character with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: I tried replacing char(11), ASCII('VT'), ASCII(11), '\t' and paste ♂ symbol in replace statement. None of them works.

Comment: Please add the replace statements to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using python:

```py
<str_value_with_VT>.replace((b'\x0b').decode(),"")
```

Comment: can you explain your Answer. How will Python help in a MS SQL Query?

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace(columnName, char(11), '')
```