# Tsql: CHARINDEX and REPLACE Dosn't recognize special character (Unicode-8207)

Tags: t-sql, unicode, special-characters, charindex

Given the following variable:

```
declare @str nvarchar(50) = 'a‏bc'
```

between 'a' and 'b' there is a hidden character which is: `nchar(8207)`

therefore:

```
select len(@str) --4
```

and:

```
select unicode(SUBSTRING(@str,2,1)) --8207
```

my problem is that I have many such records, and I have to find all these characters and delete them.

I'm trying find by `CHARINDEX` or `REPLACE` but it just does not recognize this character:

```
select CHARINDEX(Nchar(unicode(8207)),@str) --0
select REPLACE (@str , Nchar(unicode(8207)), '1') --abc
```

Comment: help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46537308/how-to-identify-unicode-text-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `REPLACE()` does indeed not work.
Looks like you will need to use `STUFF()`

```
DECLARE @Moo NVARCHAR(50) = CONCAT('a', NCHAR(8207), 'b', 'c')

SELECT   @Moo
        ,LEN(@Moo)
        ,LEN(STUFF(@moo, 2, 1, ''))
        ,STUFF(@moo, 2, 1, '')
```

However, this leaves you with having to know the locations of the offending unprintable characters. A WHILE loop or Tally table might serve you well here.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said.