# How to check language of column value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an Oracle table contains some text (VARCHAR2 type). I would like to check the language of text in the column. Something look like below. Does Oracle 11g and/or later editions have vanilla function or some third party package can do checks below or at least the code of language to distinguish?

```
SELECT <function_name>('Bonjour') FROM dual; // French

SELECT <function_name>('Bueno Dias') FROM dual; //Spanish

SELECT <function_name>('Good Morning') FROM dual; //English

SELECT <function_name>('Guten tag') FROM dual; // German
```

Comment: The short answer is Oracle has nothing out-of-the-box. Somebody asked a similar question recently, and I offered a couple of high-level suggestions. [Check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53930419/146325).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best language detect library or web api available? \[even paid\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025915/what-is-the-best-language-detect-library-or-web-api-available-even-paid)